# How to grab dynamically changing HTML names of the classes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, automated-tests

My case:

I would like to write automatic tests by using 'Test Cafe', but I have a problem with class names.

The problem is: every time (on every reload of the page) the class has a different name like for example **'Example-Class-XXX'** where **XXX** is the number. I couldn't find any solution, do you know how to select the class?

Maybe there is something similar to:

```
Selector('.Example-Class-*') or document.getElementById('Example-Class-*')
```

If you have any idea, please share. Thanks

Comment: You can select using `$('[class*="Example-Class-"]')`.. you can also add the extra class `example-class` to all the elements and select it using `document.getElementsByClassName("example-class")`

Comment: you can use attribute class as already mentioned in  answers below. 
Other than that, maybe target your nodes by properties different than class.? 
I used TestCafe with React. I ve targeted React components by props and their values (I knew values as they were mocked). 
Good luck

Answer (score 4):

You can use `document.querySelector` with attribute class.
So like this: `document.querySelector('[class^="Example-Class-"]')` For more info see this: https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/